# Session issue in IE browsers

Tags: java, internet-explorer

We are using IE 8 and the issue scenario is as below:

1. Administrator login to a admin system [Admin Session Created]
2. Administrator click on several windows passing in token simulating different user session
   [User Sessions Created] in different user application
3. Administrator logout of the admin system [Admin Session is Destroyed].
4. The different user sessions remains.

How is system able to kill off the other user sessions knowing that the admin session is destroyed?

What will be an elegant way of handling this behaviour?

Another strange thing about the session in internet explorer is that session are somehow shared. Meaning if i try to do a normal user login. The user session will actually overwrite the simulated session.

Thanks

Comment: What's the behaviour in other browsers? After reading your question, I presume you want to kill all sessions after an admin logs out?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is session merging, to start a new session select File->New Session, or start IE8 with the `-nomerge` parameter.